# Loading several data sources into an Ember UI

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to understand how to compose a page with multiple data sources and loading spinners in Ember.

Let's you have a UI like this:

http://postimg.org/image/6i1ko340f/
(sorry, don't have reputation to embed image)

And let's say each screen 'module' [books, shows, movies, tweets] has a **separate** data source at a remote  API url.

- somesite.com/api/books.json
- somesite.com/api/shows.json
- somesite.com/api/books.json
- twitter.com/api/tweets.json

In order to simplify, and get to the essence of the question, I ask that ***you don't use***:

- 1) Components
- 2) A data library (e.g. Ember Model or Ember Data) unless that's essential to the answer.

How would you approach architecting this in Ember so that each module has its own spinner and they load at their own pace (separate route hooks?).

Please help me understand how you would compose your routes, controllers, and models, or whatever else to elegantly solve this extremely common problem. I'll attach some of my approaches and thoughts in the comments :)

Comment: * I've tried thinking about this in terms of nested routes, but not sure which route I would visit to see all the modules on the same page. 
* I've also tried to think about this in terms of the special [Loading subroute](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) that Ember gives you for each route, but that doesn't help me understand the 'composing' problem at hand. I would like to use those Loading subroutes/templates if possible.

Comment: It seems to me that the it would be wicked to have a template helper (similar to 'render') that would let you compose routes a la carte on a page. That way, you could have separate data URLs, route hooks, loading states for different areas of your page. The 'render' helper as it stands doesn't give you a new route with hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this is the best way by any means, but this is how I approach that problem. Dummy [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/temodojufiqi/1/edit) using timeouts instead of async calls.

Write some sort of async wrapper. I use `ic-ajax` wrapper around `jQuery` ajax to make ajax calls that return promises in a class I call my `rest-client`. I use `initializers` to inject this object into all of my routes as `restClient` as a convenience. You can always just import when you need it.

I would normally block for my model retrieving via `Ember.RSVP.hash()` calls, but lets assume I did not as you've asked (this is our `index` route):

```
import bookModel from 'app/models/book-model';

setupController: function(controller, model){
    var self = this;
    //do this for each "module" call
    this.restClient.get('books/url').then(function(response){
        var booksController = this.controllerFor('booksTemplate');
        //data is json for the properties of your Book model
        var books = model.create(response.data);
        booksController.set('isLoading', false);
        booksController.set('model', books); 
    }); 
}
```

Make an asynchronous call, and on its success, set the model for the template's controller. Your template `books.hbs`:

```
{{#if isLoading}}
  <img src="spinner.gif">
{{else}}
  {{#each}}
    {{this.title}}
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

This template shows a spinner or while loading happens. Notice in the `setupController` call that we set `isLoading` to false on complete of the ajax call. This causes the `else` block to display.

And your `books.js` controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    isLoading: true;
});
```

And finally, your `index.hbs`:

```
{{render 'books'}}
{{render 'otherModel'}}
{{render 'anotherModel'}}
```

Caveat, if you render the same template twice with a `render` partial and do not specify the model, the two templates share a singleton instance of the controller meaning `isLoading` is shared across instances. Holler if you have any questions